# postgres: Setting the value of an array with a subquery?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, can you set the value of an array in an INSERT to the result of a subquery? Like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES( SELECT list_of_integers FROM someothertable WHERE somekey = somevalue);
```

Where that `mytable` just has as its one column a type of `integer[]` and that other column `list_of_integers` is also type `integer[]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function. I think you'd use it like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT set_of_integers
FROM unnest(
  SELECT list_of_integers
  FROM someothertable
  WHERE somekey = somevalue
) t(set_of_integers)
```

But i don't have PostgreSQL to hand to try it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
INSERT INTO
     mytable
    (column1, column2, an_array_of_integers_column)
VALUES
    (2, 'bbb', (SELECT list_of_integers FROM someothertable WHERE somekey = somevalue));
```